# Get value from different inner array twig

Tags: php, twig

How get I get the combined result from two different array i'm using twig template engine

Array:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => This is title
            [labels] => Array
                (
                    [0] => This is label-1
                    [1] => This is lable-2
                )

            [price] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 50
                    [1] => 90
                )

            [desc] => great item
            [tags] => item,great
            [time] => 1352129710
        )

)
```

What I want

- This is title
  - This is label-1 50
  - This is lable-2 90

What I tried

```
<ul>
     {% for item in market %}
    <li>{{ item.title }}</li>
    <ul>
         {% for key in item.labels %}
        <li>{{ key }} - **HOW TO DISPLAY PRICE HERE FROM [price]=>Array(..) **</li>
         {% endfor %}
    </ul>
     {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [loop](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) variable.

So : `{{item.price[loop.index0]}}`

Be careful with two things :

- Use `index0` instead of `index` or you are going to  iterate over your array
- `price` and `labels` array must have the same size

Answer (score 1):

You can try use `loop.index0` to get array index. Documentation [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#accessing-the-parent-context-in-nested-loops).

Try following code:

```
<ul>
 {% for item in market %}
<li>{{ item.title }}</li>
<ul>
     {% for key in item.labels %}
    <li>{{ key }} - {{ item.price[loop.index0] }}</li>
     {% endfor %}
</ul>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,But i'm sorry I have to check mark the other answer as @GreenLeaft posted the correct one, `[loop.index0] ` before you edit your answer